# MS Dynamics CRM 365 (online) - Performance issue inserting custom entity records with ExecuteMultipleRequest

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I'm calling `ExecuteMultipleRequest` to insert 25 records of a custom entity at a time. Each batch is taking roughly 20 seconds.
Some info about the custom entity:

- I did not create its schema and can't have it changed;
- It has 124 attributes (colums);

On each `CreateRequest` the entity has 6 attribute values filled: 2 Lookup and 4 Money. `ExecuteMultipleRequest` is being called from a middleware component in a corporate network, which connects to the CRM in the cloud. The CRM instance used is a sandbox, so it may have some restrictions (CPU/bandwidth/IO/etc), that I'm not aware of.

I can issue concurrent requests, but considering I can only have 2 concurrent requests per organization (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/jj863631.aspx#limitations), it would only cut the time in half. That is still not a viable time. 
For each new custom CRM process created I need to load at most 5000 entity records, in less than 10 minutes.

What can I do to improve the performance of this load? Where should I be looking at?
Would a DataImport (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547396.aspx) be faster than `ExecuteMultipleRequest`?

Comment: I managed ~100 records per second with the KingswaySoft Connector for SSIS

Comment: Maybe try increasing the batch size, which can be up to 1000. Also, how are you connecting to CRM? Are you using the latest CrmServiceClient?

Answer (score 0):

Only really got suggestions for this, you would probably have to experiment and investigate to see what works for you.

1. Can you run your middleware application in a physical location closer to your CRM Online site?
2. `ExecuteMultipleRequest` supports much larger batch sizes, up to 1000.
3. Have you compared to just using a single execute request.
4. Do you have lots of processes (workflows, plugins) that occur in CRM when the data import is running? This can have a big performance impact. Perhaps these can be disabled during data import. E.g. you could pre-process the data before import so a plugin wouldnt need to be executed.
5. The concurrent requests limitation only applied to `ExecuteMultipleRequest`, have you tried running lots of parallel single execute requests?

Comment: 1-I ran the middleware outside the corporate network, and got a time also around 20 secs. I'm not sure that is closer to the CRM. I'll have to check the CRM location. 2-I tried calling ExecuteMultipleRequest with a batch of 50, and got around 40 secs. 3-I have not tried a single request for this particular entity, but for others it takes slightly less than 1 sec. 4-There might be some plugins enabled that may slow down the import. I'll check with the CRM dev team. 5-For other entities I've used parallel execute requests and concluded that ExecuteMultipleRequest was faster.